# Cannot access Shared Drive/Network path with Bamboo

Tags: bamboo

Shared/Network drive not accessible through bamboo test execution

**Architecture**

Bamboo Server (Windows)

Agent (Windows)

Selenium Nodes (Windows)

Java, Cucumber and JUnit

Bitbucket

We have a requirement to access files located at some shared location while executing tests from Bamboo Plans.

All the corresponding servers have access to the shared. Manually verified.

```
File file = new File("\\\\SHARED_DRIVE\\Folder\\Automation\\download");
 System.out.println(file.exists());
 System.out.println(file.isDirectory());
 System.out.println(file.isFile());
```

Scenario 1 : Executing test through IDE (locally)

true
true
true

Scenario 2 : Executing test on Agent's VM

true
true
true

Scenario 3 : Executing test through Bamboo Plan

false
false
false

As stated above, results were false while accessing shared drive when we were executing tests though Bamboo plan.

As stated in Scenario 2, we have manually logged in to the Agent's VM and executed maven goal and checked the logs

What could be the possible issue here?

Comment: Does it accessible from Script task in Bamboo? Try to create Script task and check output: ls \\SHARED_DRIVE\Folder\Automation\download

Comment: I need to try that. However i logged in to the Bamboo server (Windows) and check for the accessibility of shared drive and i was able to. 

manually running the maven goals on bamboo's agent is also running as expected. 

Its just the Bamboo server which initiates the test on the Bamboo Agent fails to identify the shared drive.